# How can I make this code for Animations more effective?

Tags: android, xml, android-animation, android-xml

This code switches the `y-position` of two Views (mView1 and mView2) on Button click via `ObjectAnimator` and `AnimationSet`s. While the translate animation the `alpha` value of both views will be reduced and growth again. This is just a setup to play around a bit. The alpha animation is defined in XML and the translate animation is done with code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="sequentially">
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="500"
        android:valueTo="0.5"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="500"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
</set>
```

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mView1 != null && mView2 != null) {

        int top = mView2.getTop();

        ObjectAnimator translateView1 = null;
        ObjectAnimator translateView2 = null;

        if (mView1.getTranslationY() == 0) {

                translateView1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mView1, "translationY", top);
            translateView2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mView2, "translationY", top*(-1));

        } else {

                translateView1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mView2, "translationY", 0);
            translateView2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mView1, "translationY", 0);

        }

        translateView1.setDuration(1000L);
        translateView2.setDuration(1000L);

        AnimatorSet alpha1 = (AnimatorSet)AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(mCtx, R.anim.switcher);
        alpha1.setTarget(mView1);

        AnimatorSet alpha2 = (AnimatorSet)AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(mCtx, R.anim.switcher);
        alpha2.setTarget(mView2);

        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        set.playTogether(translateView1, translateView2, alpha1, alpha2);
        set.start();

    }
}
```

Now, because this is working as expected, I wanna know how I can shorten the code?

- Is it really necessary to have a seperate instance of an `AnimatorSet` for every `View`, which uses the animation from XML? Can I inflate the xml once and use it on different AnimatorSets / ObjectAnimators? Because I didn't found a setter which takes an Animator as an Argument.
- Can I define multiple targets for one AnimationSet/ObjectAnimator? Or is the only way to define different ObjectAnimators for the Views and use them in a AnimationSet?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to put the animation code inside the class that's animated ... like this :

```
public class FadingView extends View {

    private ObjectAnimator fade, moveX, moveY;
    private AnimatorSet moveSet;

    public FadingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    private void fade(int duration, float...values) {

        if(fade==null) {
            fade = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "alpha", values);
        } else {
            fade.setFloatValues(values);
        }
        fade.setDuration(duration);
        fade.start();

    }

    private void move(int duration, int x, int y) {

        if(moveX==null) {
            moveX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "translation_x", x);
        } else {
            moveX.setFloatValues(x);
        }
        if(moveY==null) {
            moveY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "translation_y", y);
        } else {
            moveY.setFloatValues(y);
        }
        if(moveSet == null) {
            moveSet = new AnimatorSet();
            moveSet.playTogether(moveX, moveY);
        }

        moveSet.setDuration(duration);
        moveSet.start();

    }

    public void moveToUpperLeft(int duration) {
        move(duration, 0,0);
    }

    public void show(int duration) {
        fade(duration,1);
    }

    public void hide(int duration) {
        fade(duration,0);
    }

}
```

Just a basic example, but now you can call :

```
FadingView view = new FadingView(context);
view.hide(500);
view.moveToUpperLeft(500);
```

Of course you can customize and generalize this even more ...